# How can I insert hard newlines into text where the text wraps in a window?

Tags: c#, windows

This question started out with someone wanting to import every apparent 'line of text' in a Word document into a row in an Excel sheet, but I'm sure this is not possible without some development.

I would like to insert a newline (whatever that may be configured as) at every point that a string is wrapped to a new line when displayed in a window. How can I do that? I figure I would need to query the window and get an array of its text lines, then count characters in each line, and in the original string, insert a newline after the number of characters that are displayed for that line.

I do of course realise that changing the window size will invalidate all the work of this code  I'm asking how to write, but that is not a relevant issue here.

**USEFUL INFO:**
I have found a solution to the original, Word to Excel export, problem. When you save a Word document as a text file, *after* you click **Save** on the Save dialogue, you are given another dialogue with an option for inserting line breaks.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Nothing. I have absolutely no idea where to start, and this is a low priority for me, so I pick the "ask first" option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is something like this:

```
int width = txtBox.width;
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

SizeF size = g.MeasureString(myText, txtBox.Font);

if (size.Width > width)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<string> lines = new List<String>();
    string str = "";
    while (i<myText.Length)
    {

        str = str + myText.SubString(i,1);
        int w = (int)(g.MeasureString(str, txtBox.Font).Width);
        while (w<width && i<myText.Length)
        {
             i++;
             str = str + myText.SubString(i,1);
        }
        str = str + '\n';
    }

    // str now contains your newline formatted string
    return str;
}
return myText;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the width of the display control and the font it is using, then use [`GetTextMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a [`TEXTMETRIC` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can be used to find out the width of each character. This is very involved as it takes into account all the different character profiles.

An easier way is to use [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx) which, given a string and the font properties, will return its width in pixels. So you can make a rough estimate as to where the line break would be, call this function on that substring, and insert a line break when the result of `GetTextExtentPoint32` is just less than the width of the text control.

Cheers.